# Cannot Import Name 'keras_export' From 'tensorflow.python.util.tf_export'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the BERT in Keras with keras_bert and tensorflow, the complete code is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/CyberZHG/keras-bert/blob/master/demo/tune/keras_bert_classification_tpu.ipynb#scrollTo=gGzsxkLTpRrs&uniqifier=1), but I am getting this error:

The error is on this line:

```
from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-eea03a4a6625> in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export

ImportError: cannot import name 'keras_export' from 'tensorflow.python.util.tf_export' (C:\Users\DILAW\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_export.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last tensorflow update have change alot of thinks, also the BERT model have a new method to use it please chek here for more information [link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/CyberZHG/keras-bert/blob/master/demo/tune/keras_bert_classification_tpu.ipynb#scrollTo=gGzsxkLTpRrs&uniqifier=1).

Answer (score 4):

Tensorflow is not uninstalled when tensorflow-gpu is install. That is the problem in importing the keras_import. So if we uninstall the tensorflow then the problem is solved.

> tensorflow_version 2.x
> !pip uninstall -y tensorflow
> !pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0

Hope it works!!